# Xamarin.Forms: How to use custom Fonts in C# Code

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, fonts

I want to use some custom Fonts `(.ttf)` in my `Xamarin.Forms` Application.
I added the two Fonts in both Projects(Android/iOS):

Now in the `XAML-Page`, I added the Fonts to the `ResourceDictionary`.
It's also possible to use the Fonts, but just in the `XAML-File`:

```
<Label Text="Test" FontFamily="{StaticResource FONT}" FontSize="Medium"/>
```

But how can I use this font in the `C#` Code?

Comment: Same as xaml you can access font family in c#  and specify like this: `FontFamily="Roboto-Regular.ttf#Roboto-Regular"` ,  as per your fonts.

Comment: please refer this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts

Comment: You should be able to access the `ResourceDictionary` in code behind: `Application.Current.Resources["MyResourceName"]`. Remember to cast this to the correct type. If you do it this way you won't have to change the font in multiple places if that's ever needed. Also I advise you to define general styles and use those in your controls (that way you can customize a lot more automatically)

Comment: @Knoop thanks for your answer. I know that it's possible to get the Resouces like that, but my problem is the cast. Whats the type of the "fontFamily"?

Comment: Ah not sure tbh, and can't check atm since I'm on a phone. However if you define a `Style` for `Label` in your `ResourceDictionary` that sets the `FontFamily` you can just cast and use that `Style` in code-behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Device.RuntimePlatform** property can be used to set different font names on each platform.

```
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
{
    label.FontFamily = "xxx.ttf";
}

else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
{
    label.FontFamily = "xxx.ttf#xxx";
}

else
{
    label.FontFamily = "Assets/Fonts/xxx.ttf#xxx";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your font from c# using the following cast:

```
var yourFont = (OnPlatform<string>)Application.Current.Resources["FONT"];
```